# Heroku App is Reading database.yml File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

From what I can gather, Heroku is supposed to generate a database.yml file automatically, and ignore the local one. However, I am seeing an error where that is not true, and my changes to the local database.yml are affecting the Heroku app. This is problematic because I have no idea how I should setup production portion of the file so Heroku can find the right database.

For instance with the following

```
production: 
    adapter: sqlite3 
    database: db/production.sqlite3 
    pool: 5 
    timeout: 5000
```

followed by the db:migration

```
$:~/Apps/DancingCupid/DancingCupid$ heroku rake --trace db:migrate
```

spits out

```
rake aborted!
unable to open database file
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:27:in `initialize' 
...
```

I can get different errors depending on what type of database I sent for production.

Besides deleting the app and making a new one, is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: How is it affecting it exactly?

Comment: Any answers as to whether or not database.yml should be pushed to heroku or not?

Answer (score 6):

Heroku definitely rewrite your database.yml on push so it doesn't matter what is in there in source control.

To confirm this do `heroku run bash` which will connect you to a bash session in your app then look do a `cat config\database.yml` and you will see how they have rewritten it.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are **NOT TRUE** anymore [as of Rails 4.1](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/426).

> config/database.yml won’t be overwritten anymore when a Rails 4.1.0
>   RC1 app is detected.  Instead, it will be merged with DATABASE_URL so
>   additional options like pool size can be set in config/database.yml.

To double-check the contents of your database.yml on the Heroku server, you can run remote bash  via `heroku run bash` and then `cat config/database.yml` to see its contents on the server and compare with your local one.

Answer (score 2):

**I don't think you are insane!** *( But I thought I was )*

I have been beating my way around this problem for a few days, and finally found this article:
http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ruby.rails.heroku/1003/match=database+yml

It led me to believe that maybe it wasn't my code at all!

I then simply destroyed my heroku app and created a new one, and pushed to it. Suddenly everything works fine! I don't know how or when or why, but I think it is possible to overwrite or corrupt the database.yml file that Heroku creates.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `database.yml` from version control. It's good practice to make a copy of `database.yml` into something like `database.yml.example` and adding `database.yml` to your `.gitignore` file.

That way when you push to Heroku it won't have any database configuration to refer to.

You probably also don't want the `sqlite3` gem in production. Make sure it's in the development/test groups in your Gemfile.

Comment: I tried this and then I got an error complaining that my database.yml file is missing. It seems that when heroku gets hosed, you get the error I'm getting.

Comment: Did you get the database.yml missing error locally or on heroku? You still need `database.yml` just not in version control. Copy it, add it to `.gitignore`. `git rm` it. Then restore your local copy.

Comment: No. I mean I get this error on Heroku. Its a bug. I reported it to Heroku too. I thought there might be workaround.

Answer (score -1):

**database.yml** should not be pushed to Heroku. It will try to connect to that database, timeout and then crash.

Add it to your **.gitignore** so it doesn't get up there.

Comment: sorry but that's not true.  heroku will write its own database.yml over yours.